# Ширина фиксированного блока = максимальная ширина страницы

Tags: css

Хочу сделать фиксированный верх страницы. Делаю так:

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 380px;
 height: 5000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

header {
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0px auto;
 position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
</body>
```

В итоге получается что фиксированный `header` уходит вправо до конца всей страницы, игнорируя `body { max-width: 380px; }`

Буду очень благодарен за помощь и объяснение!

Comment: header-у тоже можно добавить `max-width: 380px;` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fixed` позиция выбивается из обычного потока документа, и для элемента в макете страницы не создается пространство. Когда Вы объявляете её, границы положения будут фиксироваться шириной и высотой экрана. Однако, если Вы укажите `max-width` такой же как и у `body` то указанное выравнивание `margin:0 auto` будет работать верно. Так как данный блок позиционируется относительно исходного содержания блока, которое как я понял задаёт `body` как только Вы указали ему `max-width`.

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 5000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
  max-width: 380px;
}

header {
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0px auto;
 position: fixed;
  max-width: 380px;
  z-index: 9999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
</body>
```